# Filter an object array based on a string property but it is a date that is stored, and i need to return all objects where createdDate > todaysDate

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

createdDate property on my object is stored as a string, in my array of this object i need to filter for all objects where createdDate is >= todaysDate. How can i do this in typescript/javascript.

```
  notMyScrims: Scrim[];
  this.notMyScrims = this.scrims.filter(scrim => scrim.createdBy != 
  this.loggedInUser)
  console.log(this.notMyScrims);


  name?:string;
  game?:string;
  time?:string;
  level?:string;
  description?:string;
  region?:string;
  platform:string;
  acceptedBy:string;
  acceptedDate:string;
  acceptedStatus?:string;
  createdBy?:string;
  createdDate?:string;
  team?:string;
  acceptedByTeam?:string
```

this is the model for the scrim object and the array.

the date is stored as
this.createdDate = new Date().toLocaleString();

"9/25/2017"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check if you can save date as timestamp instead of a string version.

```
notMyScrims: Scrim[];
this.notMyScrims = this.scrims.filter(function(scrim) {
    return new Date(scrim.createdDate).getTime() > new Date().getTime();
});
console.log(this.notMyScrims);
```

If the date was saved in timestamp you would not need to convert it with `new Date(scrim.createdDate).getTime()`

Let me know if this helped

Comment: I am using firebase database and it does not allow timestamp storage. I can use your method for string? i still need to test.

Comment: I tested and it didn't work. :/ and i can't use timestamp or date object in firebase.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it didn't work still :/ the createdDate is in this format "10/8/2017"